# Custom columns in FullCalendar week view

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, fullcalendar

Please don't ask why as I know the oddity of this request.

I have been tasked with making a week view calendar that instead of the normal columns:

`[sat|sun|mon|tue|wed|thu|fri]`

They want it displayed as follows by having "2 day days" as well:

`[fri/sat|sat|sat/sun|sun|sun/mon|mon|mon/tue|tue|tue/wed|wed|wed/thu|thu|thu/fri|fri]`

so then if an event was on sat into Sunday it would show on the [sat/sun] column, if it was just Saturday it'd show on the [sat] column.

They already have FullCalendar so this is the preferred method... if it can be modified to work this way.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This sounds a bit of a bonkers layout to my mind. Would be quite confusing to users IMO. What's wrong with the events just overlapping across days? Then you can see which events coincide with which others much more easily.

Comment: I completely agree with you... but this client has “done it this way for decades” and is not amenable to doing it the sensible way.

Comment: But that aside, no this can't be done with any of the default functionality. If you _really really_ wanted to do it, you'd be treading deep into the territory of custom views (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js) which is not somewhere you want to go unless you're 100% sure you need the feature. It's a time-consuming and complicated process (just look at the code for any of the existing views on GitHub) and then you have to maintain it to keep it up to date with ongoing changes to fullCalendar. Think very carefully before you go down this road.

Comment: I'm also not personally aware of any other calendar tool which has such a capability. Mainly because no-one would ever want it. I love the "this is the way we've always done it and we don't care if it's insane or not" attitude. If the world was left to these people we would all still be making tools out of flint and scratching pictures of mammoths on cave walls.

Comment: If it was me I'd make a quick little demo showing the sane way to do it and see if they really can't manage to extract the same meaning from it as from their older layout. The only thing which actually matters in the end is whether they can efficiently understand the info they need to know when viewing it. Were they using some custom bit of software to draw it, or just on paper, or what?